# Buildbox to APK android using Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

guys, i have a problem launching my game on my phone or any virtual device, I've exported the game from Buildbox to an android source code and imported into eclipse without any problem and export it to android application also with no problem, when I tried to test the game on my device crushed "Unfortunately App name has stopped", I've run it on my virtual device and those are the logs that gave me.

```
10-20 10:48:50.421: D/dalvikvm(1735): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.crunchapps.towercube-2/libplayer.so 0x94f1dd90
10-20 10:48:50.651: D/dalvikvm(1735): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.crunchapps.towercube-2/libplayer.so 0x94f1dd90
10-20 10:48:50.651: D/JniHelper(1735): JniHelper::setJavaVM(0xb8238d40), pthread_self() = -1217091840
10-20 10:48:50.681: D/Cocos2dxActivity(1735): model=N918St
10-20 10:48:50.691: D/Cocos2dxActivity(1735): product=N918St
10-20 10:48:50.691: D/Cocos2dxActivity(1735): isEmulator=false
10-20 10:48:50.711: V/PTServicesBridge(1735): PTServicesBridge  -- INIT
10-20 10:48:50.711: D/PTPlayer(1735): [PTPSettingsController] - loadInventoryMap
10-20 10:48:50.781: D/libEGL(1735): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno.so
10-20 10:48:50.791: D/(1735): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb83b0e90, tid 1735
10-20 10:48:50.791: D/libEGL(1735): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
10-20 10:48:50.801: D/libEGL(1735): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
10-20 10:48:50.821: D/OpenGLRenderer(1735): Enabling debug mode 0
10-20 10:48:50.831: D/(1735): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb83b8130, tid 1747
10-20 10:48:57.411: D/PTPlayer(1735): End loading XML
10-20 10:48:57.411: D/PTPlayer(1735): [PTPSettingsController] - loadInventoryMap
10-20 10:48:57.421: D/PTPlayer(1735): [PTPSettingsController] - load
10-20 10:48:57.451: D/PTPlayer(1735): invenotory count: 0
10-20 10:48:57.451: D/PTPlayer(1735): characters count: 1
10-20 10:48:57.451: D/PTPlayer(1735): load character: PTP_Character_0 = 0:1
10-20 10:48:57.461: D/PTPlayer(1735): [PTPSettingsController] - load complete
10-20 10:48:57.461: D/PTPlayer(1735): Init Android JNI Bridges
10-20 10:48:57.471: V/PTAdAdMobBridge(1735): PTAdAdMobBridge  -- INIT
10-20 10:48:57.481: D/PTPlayer(1735): Platform: Google Play
10-20 10:48:57.501: D/PTStoreBridge(1735): Problem setting up In-app Billing: IabResult: Error checking for billing v3 support. (response: 3:Billing Unavailable)
10-20 10:48:57.501: I/dalvikvm(1735): Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzi
10-20 10:48:57.501: W/dalvikvm(1735): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 425: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
10-20 10:48:57.501: D/dalvikvm(1735): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
10-20 10:48:57.571: I/dalvikvm(1735): Could not find method android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy.getInstance, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.state.f.a
10-20 10:48:57.571: W/dalvikvm(1735): VFY: unable to resolve static method 2821: Landroid/security/NetworkSecurityPolicy;.getInstance ()Landroid/security/NetworkSecurityPolicy;
10-20 10:48:57.581: D/dalvikvm(1735): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x00d5
10-20 10:48:57.701: D/dalvikvm(1735): JIT code cache reset in 0 ms (0 bytes 1/0)
10-20 10:48:57.701: D/dalvikvm(1735): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 316K, 12% free 2902K/3284K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
10-20 10:48:57.711: I/dalvikvm(1735): Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method ikr.a
10-20 10:48:57.711: W/dalvikvm(1735): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2158: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
10-20 10:48:57.711: D/dalvikvm(1735): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x001c
10-20 10:48:57.731: I/dalvikvm(1735): Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.createCredentialProtectedStorageContext, referenced from method hko.createCredentialProtectedStorageContext
10-20 10:48:57.731: W/dalvikvm(1735): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2050: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.createCredentialProtectedStorageContext ()Landroid/content/Context;
10-20 10:48:57.731: D/dalvikvm(1735): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0002
10-20 10:48:57.731: I/dalvikvm(1735): Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext, referenced from method hko.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext
10-20 10:48:57.731: W/dalvikvm(1735): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2051: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext ()Landroid/content/Context;
10-20 10:48:57.741: D/dalvikvm(1735): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0002
10-20 10:48:57.741: I/dalvikvm(1735): Could not find method com.google.android.chimera.ContextThemeWrapper.createCredentialProtectedStorageContext, referenced from method com.google.android.chimera.ModuleContext.createCredentialProtectedStorageContext
10-20 10:48:57.741: W/dalvikvm(1735): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 8237: Lcom/google/android/chimera/ContextThemeWrapper;.createCredentialProtectedStorageContext ()Landroid/content/Context;
10-20 10:48:57.751: D/dalvikvm(1735): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0002
10-20 10:48:57.751: I/dalvikvm(1735): Could not find method com.google.android.chimera.ContextThemeWrapper.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext, referenced from method com.google.android.chimera.ModuleContext.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext
10-20 10:48:57.751: W/dalvikvm(1735): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 8238: Lcom/google/android/chimera/ContextThemeWrapper;.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext ()Landroid/content/Context;
10-20 10:48:57.751: D/dalvikvm(1735): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0002
10-20 10:48:57.761: I/dalvikvm(1735): Could not find method android.content.Context.isCredentialProtectedStorage, referenced from method bvv.a
10-20 10:48:57.761: W/dalvikvm(1735): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2030: Landroid/content/Context;.isCredentialProtectedStorage ()Z
10-20 10:48:57.761: D/dalvikvm(1735): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0000
10-20 10:48:57.761: I/dalvikvm(1735): Could not find method android.os.UserManager.isUserUnlocked, referenced from method bvv.a
10-20 10:48:57.761: W/dalvikvm(1735): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2796: Landroid/os/UserManager;.isUserUnlocked ()Z
10-20 10:48:57.771: D/dalvikvm(1735): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x001a
10-20 10:48:57.771: I/dalvikvm(1735): Could not find method android.content.Context.isDeviceProtectedStorage, referenced from method bvv.b
10-20 10:48:57.771: W/dalvikvm(1735): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2031: Landroid/content/Context;.isDeviceProtectedStorage ()Z
10-20 10:48:57.771: D/dalvikvm(1735): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0000
10-20 10:48:57.771: I/dalvikvm(1735): Could not find method android.content.Context.isDeviceProtectedStorage, referenced from method bvv.c
10-20 10:48:57.771: W/dalvikvm(1735): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2031: Landroid/content/Context;.isDeviceProtectedStorage ()Z
10-20 10:48:57.771: D/dalvikvm(1735): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0000
10-20 10:48:57.791: E/ChimeraCfgMgr(1735): Failed to read module config: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/current_config.pb: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
10-20 10:48:57.791: W/DynamiteUtils(1735): Failed to load module: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/current_config.pb: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
10-20 10:48:57.791: W/DynamiteUtils(1735): Attempt 1 failed.
10-20 10:48:57.931: E/ChimeraCfgMgr(1735): Failed to read module config: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/current_config.pb: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
10-20 10:48:57.931: W/DynamiteUtils(1735): Failed to load module: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/current_config.pb: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
10-20 10:48:57.931: W/DynamiteUtils(1735): Attempt 2 failed.
10-20 10:48:58.031: E/ChimeraCfgMgr(1735): Failed to read module config: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/current_config.pb: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
10-20 10:48:58.031: W/DynamiteUtils(1735): Failed to load module: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/current_config.pb: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
10-20 10:48:58.031: W/DynamiteUtils(1735): Attempt 3 failed.
10-20 10:48:58.031: I/dalvikvm(1735): Could not find method android.system.Os.symlink, referenced from method com.google.android.chimera.container.FileApkManager.a
10-20 10:48:58.031: W/dalvikvm(1735): VFY: unable to resolve static method 2826: Landroid/system/Os;.symlink (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
10-20 10:48:58.031: D/dalvikvm(1735): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0032
10-20 10:48:58.041: W/DynamiteUtils(1735): Client module failure reason: 1
10-20 10:48:58.051: D/DynamitePackage(1735): Module could not be loaded.
10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735): Failed to load ads dynamite module.
10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735): android.os.RemoteException
10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735):    at cwx.<init>(:com.google.android.gms:37)
10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735):    at cwx.a(:com.google.android.gms:23)
10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735):    at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsSettingManagerCreatorImpl.getMobileAdsSettingManager(:com.google.android.gms:38)
10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735):    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.bc.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms:55)
10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735):    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzz$zza$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735):    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzaf.zzv(Unknown Source)
10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735):    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzaf.zzu(Unknown Source)
10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735):    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzad.initialize(Unknown Source)
10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735):    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzad.zza(Unknown Source)
10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735):    at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(Unknown Source)
10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735):    at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(Unknown Source)
10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735):    at com.secrethq.ads.PTAdAdMobBridge.initBridge(PTAdAdMobBridge.java:38)
10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735):    at com.crunchapps.towercube.PTPlayer.initBridges(PTPlayer.java:74)
10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735):    at com.crunchapps.towercube.PTPlayer.onNativeInit(PTPlayer.java:58)
10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735):    at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxHelper.onNativeInitStatic(Cocos2dxHelper.java:106)
10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735):    at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer.nativeRender(Native Method)
10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735):    at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer.onDrawFrame(Cocos2dxRenderer.java:95)
10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1523)
10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
10-20 10:48:58.131: D/DynamitePackage(1735): Instantiated singleton DynamitePackage.
10-20 10:48:58.131: V/PTAdAdMobBridge(1735): PTAdAdMobBridge  -- initBanner
10-20 10:48:58.141: V/PTAdAdMobBridge(1735): PTAdAdMobBridge  -- initInterstitial
10-20 10:48:58.141: D/PTPlayer(1735): Platform: Google Play
10-20 10:48:58.141: E/PTServicesBridge(1735): PTServicesBridge  -- loadingDidComplete
10-20 10:48:58.151: V/PTServicesBridge(1735): PTServicesBridge  -- Login Game Services 
10-20 10:48:58.151: D/PTPlayer(1735): [PTAdController] init Ad Networks
10-20 10:48:58.151: D/PTPlayer(1735): Platform: Google Play
10-20 10:48:58.151: W/dalvikvm(1735): dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'com/secrethq/ads/PTAdHeyzapBridge'
10-20 10:48:58.151: D/PTPlayer(1735): Start Atlas loading
10-20 10:48:58.161: D/PTPlayer(1735): loading atlas
10-20 10:48:58.161: D/PTPlayer(1735): data/atlases/atlas_ID107.plist
10-20 10:48:58.201: I/dalvikvm(1735): Could not find method android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy.getInstance, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.internal.zzih.zzb
10-20 10:48:58.211: W/dalvikvm(1735): VFY: unable to resolve static method 1123: Landroid/security/NetworkSecurityPolicy;.getInstance ()Landroid/security/NetworkSecurityPolicy;
10-20 10:48:58.211: D/dalvikvm(1735): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0034
10-20 10:48:58.381: V/WebViewChromium(1735): Binding Chromium to the main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {4a78c4d4}
10-20 10:48:58.381: I/chromium(1735): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
10-20 10:48:58.411: I/BrowserProcessMain(1735): Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
10-20 10:48:58.591: W/chromium(1735): [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
10-20 10:48:58.641: D/dalvikvm(1735): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 333K, 12% free 3081K/3480K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
10-20 10:48:58.681: I/Ads(1735): Starting ad request.
10-20 10:48:58.681: I/Ads(1735): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("166B97F0EFD7023D46BBE8FA6EB790AC") to get test ads on this device.
10-20 10:48:58.691: I/Choreographer(1735): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-20 10:48:58.701: D/PTPlayer(1735): Platform: Google Play
10-20 10:48:58.701: W/Ads(1735): Using InterstitialAdManager from the client jar.
10-20 10:48:58.711: I/Ads(1735): Starting ad request.
10-20 10:48:58.711: I/Ads(1735): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("166B97F0EFD7023D46BBE8FA6EB790AC") to get test ads on this device.
10-20 10:48:58.721: D/dalvikvm(1735): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads940300955.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
10-20 10:48:59.721: D/PTPlayer(1735): loading atlas
10-20 10:48:59.721: D/PTPlayer(1735): data/atlases/atlas_ID2601.plist
10-20 10:49:00.971: D/PTPlayer(1735): loading atlas
10-20 10:49:00.971: D/PTPlayer(1735): data/atlases/atlas_ID2721.plist
10-20 10:49:01.561: D/PTPlayer(1735): loading atlas
10-20 10:49:01.561: D/PTPlayer(1735): data/atlases/atlas_ID3564.plist
10-20 10:49:02.791: D/PTPlayer(1735): loading atlas
10-20 10:49:02.841: D/PTPlayer(1735): data/atlases/atlas_ID3776.plist
10-20 10:49:03.521: D/PTPlayer(1735): loading screens
10-20 10:49:03.621: D/DeviceTypeRuntimeCheck(1735): Running on a non-TV Device
10-20 10:49:03.631: D/PTPlayer(1735): [PTPScreenMainMenuUI] banner: kAdMob interstitial: kNoAds
10-20 10:49:03.631: V/PTAdAdMobBridge(1735): showBannerAd
10-20 10:49:03.631: W/Ads(1735): Loading already in progress, saving this object for future refreshes.
10-20 10:49:05.331: W/AudioSystem(1735): AudioPolicyService server died!
10-20 10:49:07.521: D/DeviceTypeRuntimeCheck(1735): Running on a non-TV Device
10-20 10:49:07.521: D/PTPlayer(1735): [PTPScreen] banner will show for: PTPScreenMainMenu
10-20 10:49:07.531: D/PTPlayer(1735): [PTPSettingsController] - save
10-20 10:49:07.551: D/PTPlayer(1735): [PTPSettingsController] - save complete
10-20 10:49:07.571: D/PTPlayer(1735): [PTPScreen] banner will show for: PTPScreenMainMenu
10-20 10:49:07.571: D/PTPlayer(1735): [PTPScreenMainMenu] banner: kAdMob interstitial: kNoAds
10-20 10:49:07.571: D/PTPlayer(1735): [PTAdController] banner already visible
10-20 10:49:07.571: D/PTPlayer(1735): [PTPScreenScene 1] banner: kNoAds interstitial: kNoAds
10-20 10:49:07.571: D/PTPlayer(1735): [PTAdController] banner already visible
10-20 10:49:07.581: D/PTPlayer(1735): [PTPScreenScene] - flash: 0.000000
10-20 10:49:07.581: D/PTPlayer(1735): [PTPScreenScene] - shake: 0.000000
10-20 10:49:07.581: D/PTPlayer(1735): add level section: 1334
10-20 10:49:07.581: D/PTPlayer(1735): [start] updaing object creation queue
10-20 10:49:07.591: D/PTPlayer(1735): character created
10-20 10:49:07.631: D/PTPlayer(1735): updaing object creation queue
10-20 10:49:07.631: D/PTPlayer(1735): [PTPSettingsController] - save
10-20 10:49:07.651: D/PTPlayer(1735): [PTPSettingsController] - save complete
10-20 10:49:07.701: D/dalvikvm(1735): DexOpt: --- END 'ads940300955.jar' (success) ---
10-20 10:49:07.721: D/dalvikvm(1735): DEX prep '/data/data/com.crunchapps.towercube/cache/ads940300955.jar': unzip in 18ms, rewrite 8994ms
10-20 10:49:09.651: W/AudioSystem(1735): AudioFlinger server died!
10-20 10:49:09.651: W/IMediaDeathNotifier(1735): media server died
10-20 10:49:09.651: E/libOpenSLES(1735): Error (-2147483648) encountered while prefetching
10-20 10:49:16.311: W/AudioSystem(1735): AudioPolicyService server died!
10-20 10:49:18.411: D/dalvikvm(1735): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 435K, 14% free 3159K/3660K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
10-20 10:49:18.451: I/dalvikvm(1735): Could not find method android.webkit.WebSettings.setMixedContentMode, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.internal.zzjt.<init>
10-20 10:49:18.451: W/dalvikvm(1735): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 5893: Landroid/webkit/WebSettings;.setMixedContentMode (I)V
10-20 10:49:18.451: D/dalvikvm(1735): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0053
10-20 10:49:18.481: D/dalvikvm(1735): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 45K, 13% free 3209K/3688K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
10-20 10:49:18.501: I/dalvikvm-heap(1735): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.464MB for 281892-byte allocation
10-20 10:49:18.511: D/dalvikvm(1735): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 13% free 3484K/3964K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
10-20 10:49:21.031: A/libc(1735): Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL) at 0x81ee5639 (code=2), thread 1835 (happs.towercube)
```

Comment: this is the full log file https://jpst.it/16pR7

Comment: Can you catch ust the `System.err`, `AndroidRuntime`, `dalvikvm` and `libc` logs?
`adb logcat *:s System.err:v AndroidRuntime:v dalvikvm:v libc:v DEBUG:v` ?

Comment: How can i do that Shark?

Comment: I gave you the logcat command for it.. but it seems to be either a missing method, or a missing module problem on first look.

Did you try debugging it?

Comment: Hey shark i've executed the command that you gave me i'll send u the output right now.

Comment: here is the Output : https://justpaste.it/1clqu

Comment: Native crashes are killing your app... suggest you rebuild/update your native libraries. But since you're doing that from buildbox, thats probably not going to happen... file an issue on their issue tracker, maybe they're using old precompiled versions that are incompatible with your device(s)

Answer (score 0):

These seem to be the most relevant logs I saw...

> 10-20 10:48:58.051: D/DynamitePackage(1735): Module could not be loaded.
>   10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735): Failed to load ads dynamite module.
>   10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735): android.os.RemoteException
>   10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735): at cwx.(:com.google.android.gms:37)
>
> 10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735): at cwx.a(:com.google.android.gms:23)
>   10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735): at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsSettingManagerCreatorImpl.getMobileAdsSettingManager(:com.google.android.gms:38)
>   10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735): at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.bc.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms:55)
>   10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735): at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
>   10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735): at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzz$zza$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
>   10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735): at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzaf.zzv(Unknown Source)
>   10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735): at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzaf.zzu(Unknown Source)
>   10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735): at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzad.initialize(Unknown Source)
>   10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735): at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzad.zza(Unknown Source)
>   10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735): at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(Unknown Source)
>   10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735): at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(Unknown Source)
>   10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735): at com.secrethq.ads.PTAdAdMobBridge.initBridge(PTAdAdMobBridge.java:38)
>   10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735): at com.crunchapps.towercube.PTPlayer.initBridges(PTPlayer.java:74)
>   10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735): at com.crunchapps.towercube.PTPlayer.onNativeInit(PTPlayer.java:58)
>   10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735): at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxHelper.onNativeInitStatic(Cocos2dxHelper.java:106)
>   10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735): at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer.nativeRender(Native Method)
>   10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735): at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer.onDrawFrame(Cocos2dxRenderer.java:95)
>   10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1523)
>   10-20 10:48:58.131: E/DynamitePackage(1735): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
>   ... 
>   10-20 10:49:18.451: I/dalvikvm(1735): Could not find method android.webkit.WebSettings.setMixedContentMode, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.internal.zzjt.
>   10-20 10:49:18.451: W/dalvikvm(1735): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 5893: Landroid/webkit/WebSettings;.setMixedContentMode (I)V

So did you make sure that the `setMixedContentMode` method is there, and that GMS is installed on the device?

Comment: no i've just exported from buildbox and build it using eclipse